# How to get data from GSM module to android studio without including the server?

Tags: android, gsm

I am trying to get GSM data into the android studio. However, this data must not come through the server.
Basically, sending the data from GSM module from Arduino to android application without including any type of server such as Firebase. Need help

Comment: If you send data over GSM it has to come from the Internet, meaning some sort of server. If you want Arduino to communicate with a phone, you have options of WiFi, Bluetooth, BLE and maybe NFC. What are the requirements? What is the application (not the app, but what are you trying to do)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking a bit of interest in the question. So, I am trying to create a vehicle tracking system. Simple flow chart for the data :- GPS -> Arduino ->GSM -> Mobile application. However, I do not want to use WIFI, Bluetooth and NFC. On googling some folks were telling to use TCP/IP sockets(do they include server?).

Comment: Sockets communication requires a server, MQTT server for exaple (look for Mosquitto, it has library for almost every platform) to connect between Arduino and your mobile app, unless there is a way to have one of them act as a server but that would complicate the project a lot (and yet, msybe someone has done it, maybe look at that direction). Anyway, strait forward solutions would include some sort of server, Sockets or http/s, it doesn't matter.